# list redirect destinations (URL) IIS sites

Tags: powershell, iis, appcmd, web-administration

I have several redirect sites configured in IIS 8.5, and I want to list them all. I've tried:

```
.\appcmd.exe list site * -section:system.webServer/httpRedirect
```

but wildcards are not working fine with `appcmd`. I also tried from the `WebAdministration` module:

```
Get-WebConfiguration system.webServer/httpRedirect * | Get-Member destination
```

but this is also not delivering what I need...  which is a list with 2 columns for site & destination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This snippet will give you the sitenames and httpredirect destinations :

```
Get-Website | select name,@{name='destination';e={(Get-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/httpRedirect -name "destination" -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$($_.name)").value}}
```

For fetching just the destinations:

```
(Get-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/httpRedirect -name "destination" -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\*').value
```

Comment: Hello - While I am thankfull for this answer and I have been using it for long. I am starting to get OOM errors when running this tiny piece of code against servers with 1000+ redirects. Any ideas how to improve it in order to not get the OOM error? @abhijith-pk

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to below function to address this issue.

```
Function Get-IISRedirectURLs { 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param 
    ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String]$SiteName 
    ) 

    If ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($SiteName)) { 
        Get-Website | ForEach-Object { 
            $SiteName = $_.Name 
            $prop = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/httpRedirect -name 'destination' -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$SiteName" 
            Write-Host "$SiteName`t$($prop.value)" 
        } 

    } Else { 
        $prop = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/httpRedirect -name 'destination' -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$SiteName" 
        Write-Host "$SiteName`t$($prop.value)" 
    } 
}
```

For the complete sample archive, please download from [How to list redirect destination URLs of IIS sites by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-list-redirect-d50a7cb9)